# Как избежать утечки памяти (динамическое выделение в вызываемой функции)

Tags: c, утечка-памяти, malloc

Есть задача на чистом С (С 11), написать функцию с прототипом:
void *to_upper(const char *str)
Должна возвращать указатель на копию строки str, где все символы переведены в верхний регистр. Я реализовал её так:

```
void *to_upper(const char *str) {
    void *res = NULL;
    ssize_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *str1 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (*(str + i) > 96 && *(str + i) < 123)
            *(str1 + i) = *(str + i) - 32;
        else
            *(str1 + i) = *(str + i);
        res = (void*) str1;
    }
    *(str1 + len) = '\0';
    return res;
}
```

Но я так понимаю, что выделив динамически память для новой строки и не освободив её, я получаю утечку каждый раз как будет использована эта функция. **Есть ли способ реализации данной функции исключающий утечку памяти?**

Comment: Передавайте в функцию указатель на строку-приемник. Так вы полностью передадите ответственность за все вызывающей функции. Если бы существовал способ полностью избежать утечек памяти — думаю, он бы был внесен в стандарт языка...

Comment: Не могу, т.к. условия задачи жестко ограничивают сигнатуру функции, я не могу вводить новые аргументы.

Comment: Думаю, за освобождение памяти отвечает тот, кто вызывает функцию, то есть в данном случае не вы

Comment: Тогда просто написать в документации, чтоб пользователь не забывал память освобождать... Или менять саму исходную строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никто не мешает сделать статический буфер и возвращать на него указатель. Правда по выходу с функции его лучше сразу себе скопировать. Более того, такой прием используется в некоторых функциях в системных библиотеках. Я вот набросал пример в таком же стиле, как и код в вопросе

```
void *to_upper(const char *str) {
    #define MLEN 4096
    static char buffer[MLEN];
    ssize_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    if (len >= MLEN) return NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
            buffer[i] = str[i] - 32;
        else
            buffer[i] = str[i];
    }
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    return &buffer;
}
```

тут как всегда, 4кб хватит всем:) Также я заменил магические константы на реальные символы.

Также такой прием часто используется в "нагруженном" коде, где лишние выделения памяти не нужны.

Такие функции просто так нельзя использовать в двух потоках одновременно. Но это можно исправить.

--- upd ---

Но что делать, если это собеседование и там @avp и спрашивает: "а я хочу, что бы такой код

```
int main()
{
    printf("%s %s\n", (char *)to_upper("data"), (char *)to_upper("foo"));
}
```

работал правильно. Ну хотя бы почти всегда правильно"?

Ответим таким кодом.

```
void *to_upper(const char *str) {
    #define MLEN 4096
    #define SIZE 16
    static char buffer[SIZE][MLEN];
    static int pos = SIZE-1;
    pos = (pos + 1) % SIZE;
    ssize_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    if (len >= MLEN) return NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
            buffer[pos][i] = str[i] - 32;
        else
            buffer[pos][i] = str[i];
    }
    buffer[pos][len] = '\0';
    return &buffer[pos];
}
```

у нас теперь не один буфер, а 16. И каждый новый запрос обслуживается с отдельного буфера. Да, когда они будут ходить по кругу, но в большинстве случаев, даже многопоточное использование заработает (если обеспечить потокобезопасный инкремент и правильный выбор буфера. Но эти доделки, это задача для старых синьоров, когда им нечем заняться.

Comment: Их даже нельзя использовать, например, вот так -- `printf("%s %s\n", (char *)to_upper(s1), (char *)to_upper(s2));`

Comment: Если буквально чуточку поправить, то можно

Comment: Ничего кроме как обернуть в `strdup()` в голову не приходит...

Comment: Читать ваши дискуссии истинное удовольствие. Помимо заданного вопроса узнаешь ещё какую-нибудь полезную фишечку)))

Comment: Но анонимный минусатор и тут пришел и потыкал.

Comment: кстати, функция strdup как раз долго не была "стандартной" - потому что она скрывала выделение памяти и не давала возможности передать свой "аллокатор"

Answer (score 1):

**Несерьезный ответ:**

Дописать сверху комментарий:

```
//Кто забудет вызвать free() для полученного 
//отсюда указателя будет уволен на месте!
```

**Более серьезный ответ:**

В старом-добром DOOM за это отвечал механизм, называемый [Zone Memory](https://doom.fandom.com/wiki/Zone_memory). Идея состояла в том, что память динамически выделялась из общего пула, а потом, когда в работе игры происходил переход между уровнями, и данные становились точно не нужны - память вычищалась сразу вся.

Вы можете поступить аналогично - выделить в работе приложения какой-то момент, когда все выделенные строки точно потеряли актуальность - и снести их разом.

Comment: ))) Задача не столько практического применения, сколько академического. Это именно задача которую нужно решить соблюдая поставленные условия. Решение у неё есть, и его нужно найти)) В этом смысл самой задачи. Я уже голову сломал думая над ней.

Comment: @Escator очередное "пойди туда, не знаю куда" с собеседования?

Comment: @Escator Тогда решение единственное - кто вызвал функцию, тот сам дергает `free`.

Comment: @gbg не собеседование, учебный проект)))